# Conditional custom rows in pyqt4 QFileSystemModel

Tags: qt, pyqt4

I want to add custom rows in QFileSystemModel under QTreeview. The row is only added when the directory contains files with a certain extension. Basically, After starting up the directory listing, the user will click through the folders. As soon as the folder the user clicked contains the target file, I would like to hide these files (which I know how to do), then use custom rows to represent a summary of these files.

For example, if the folder contains files like the following

```
A.01.dat
A.02.dat
A.03.dat
...
B.01.dat
B.02.dat
B.03.dat
```

I would like to create custom rows:

```
A
B
```

However, if the folder clicked does not contain these .dat files, then no custom rows should be created.

I have also tried to insert rows directly into QFileSystemModel

```
self.treeivew.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
```

...

```
for n, s in enumerate(self.sequence):
        self.treeview.model.beginInsertRows(index, 0, 0)
        result = self.treeview.model.insertRow(1, index)
        print(result)
        self.treeview.model.setData(index, QString(s['Name']),role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.treeview.model.endInsertRows()
```

But the insertion failed.

If reimplementation is necessary, as I have seen many places have suggested, can anyone provide a **concrete** example on how the reimplementation should be done to allow such conditional custom row insertion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement an item model with dynamic child insertion.  This is just a standard `QAbstractItemModel` with a few extra methods -

- [rowCount](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowCount) - you would normally implement this for a tree model anyway.  Just make sure that it returns 0 if the node has children that have not been loaded yet.
- [hasChildren](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#hasChildren) - override to return `True` for nodes that have children that haven't been loaded yet and return whatever the base class returns in all other cases.
- [canFetchMore](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore) - return `True` if the node has children that haven't been loaded yet, `False` otherwise.
- [fetchMore](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore) - this is where you perform whatever logic you need to decide what nodes to create and insert them into the model.

Here's the basic idea - for nodes that you know have children that haven't been loaded, return 0 from `rowCount` and  `True` from `canFetchMore` and `hasChildren`.  This tells Qt to show a node with an expander next to it even though it currently has no children.  When the expander is clicked, `fetchMore` is called  and you populate the children from the given parent.

One thing to note - you must call `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows` in the `fetchMore` method. What's more, you musn't change the underlying datastore before calling `beginInsertRows` or after `endInsertRows`.  Unfortunately, you need to know how many rows you are inserting when you call `beginInsertRows` - so you are probably going to want to generate a list of nodes to add, then make the call to `beginInsertRows`.  If you do it this way though, you can't set the new nodes' parent, as it would change the underlying datastore.

You can see in the code below, that I set the parent node in the `Node.insert_child` method which is called between the `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows` calls.

The code doesn't do exactly what you are after - it's a basic file system model illustrating dynamic loading, you'll need to insert you custom logic to generate the category nodes you want in the `fetchMore` call.  It also only shows the filename and lacks icons.

If you want the modified date and size to be shown, you'll need to store these in the relevant nodes and set the model `columnCount` method to return the correct number of columns.

For icons, extend the model `data` method to check for the `Qt.DecorationRole` and return the relevant `QIcon`.

There might be some superfluous stuff in the code as it's a cut down and repurposed model from something else.

```
import sys
import os

import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, name, path=None, parent=None):
        super(Node, self).__init__()

        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        self.parent = parent

        self.is_dir = False
        self.path = path
        self.is_traversed = False

        if parent is not None:
            parent.add_child(self)

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)
        child.parent = self

    def insert_child(self, position, child):
        if position < 0 or position > self.child_count():
            return False

        self.children.insert(position, child)
        child.parent = self

        return True

    def child(self, row):
        return self.children[row]

    def child_count(self):
        return len(self.children)

    def row(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return self.parent.children.index(self)
        return 0


class FileSystemTreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):

    FLAG_DEFAULT = Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def __init__(self, root, path='c:/', parent=None):
        super(FileSystemTreeModel, self).__init__()

        self.root = root
        self.parent = parent
        self.path = path

        for file in os.listdir(path):
            file_path = os.path.join(path, file)

            node = Node(file, file_path, parent=self.root)
            if os.path.isdir(file_path):
                node.is_dir = True

    def getNode(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return index.internalPointer()
        else:
            return self.root

    ## - dynamic row insertion starts here
    def canFetchMore(self, index):
        node = self.getNode(index)

        if node.is_dir and not node.is_traversed:
            return True

        return False

    ## this is where you put custom logic for handling your special nodes
    def fetchMore(self, index):
        parent = self.getNode(index)

        nodes = []
        for file in os.listdir(parent.path):
            file_path = os.path.join(parent.path, file)

            node = Node(file, file_path)
            if os.path.isdir(file_path):
                node.is_dir = True

            nodes.append(node)

        self.insertNodes(0, nodes, index)
        parent.is_traversed = True

    def hasChildren(self, index):
        node = self.getNode(index)

        if node.is_dir:
            return True

        return super(FileSystemTreeModel, self).hasChildren(index)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        node = self.getNode(parent)
        return node.child_count()

    ## dynamic row insert ends here

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def flags(self, index):
        return FileSystemTreeModel.FLAG_DEFAULT

    def parent(self, index):
        node = self.getNode(index)

        parent = node.parent
        if parent == self.root:
            return QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parent.row(), 0, parent)

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        node = self.getNode(parent)

        child = node.child(row)

        if not child:
            return QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(row, column, child)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        return self.root.name

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        node = index.internalPointer()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return node.name

        else:
            return None

    def insertNodes(self, position, nodes, parent=QModelIndex()):
        node = self.getNode(parent)

        self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + len(nodes) - 1)

        for child in nodes:
            success = node.insert_child(position, child)

        self.endInsertRows()

        return success



app = QApplication(sys.argv)

model = FileSystemTreeModel(Node('Filename'), path='c:/')


tree = QTreeView()
tree.setModel(model)

tree.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank your very much, Tim. This is very helpful.